# jQuery wildcard in middle of known characters

Tags: jquery, wildcard

I have to make something happen only on a specific page of the website.
Url is www.site.com/user/43247/edit - but the numbers in between user and edit will change based on what user is logged in.

I started with:

```
if ($(location).attr('pathname').indexOf("/user") >= 0){
 action;
}
```

And that was working, but it also touched a page it should not have, so I need to match `/user/WILDCARD/edit`

I tried `/user/^/edit` as I thought `^` would work as wildcard but alas it does not.

Comment: have you tried using regular expressions?

Comment: No I have not. I need to match that url with a wildcard for the numbers inside an if statement. I need to make something happen on page but do not have access to the files or css, only to an attached script, so I figure I can change the dom elemtents via jQuery which is loaded on the site.

Pardon my ignorance, but can I use a regex to match inside an if statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to help match strings.

Here's how you could do it in this case:

```
var siteUrl = "www.site.com/user/43247/edit";
var regExpression = /www.site.com\/user\/([0-9]*)\/edit/;
var userID = siteUrl.match(regExpression)[1]; //has value "43247"
```

Here's a site that can help you build a regular expression: https://regex101.com/r/aW0vQ3/1

Comment: Doesn't get any simpler than this. Though OP could arguably shave off `/www.site.com\/`.

Comment: yeah, i just wanted to keep it as clear as I could for him what it was doing.